# Difference in asn1 decode & encode

Tags: python-3.x, decode, encode, asn.1

I'm trying to decode and encode a QR code.
The QR code is base45 encoded and after that asn1 encoded.
Decoding works fine.
After this I would like to encode it again.
There is a little difference between the base45 decoded and the asn1-encoded result.

This is the code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from typing import List, Dict, Optional
from PIL import Image
from pyzbar import pyzbar

import asn1
import json
import qrcode

def base45decode_nl(s: str) -> bytes:
    base45_nl_charset = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ $%*+-./:"

    s_len = len(s)
    res = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        f = base45_nl_charset.index(c)
        w = 45 ** (s_len - i - 1)
        res += f * w
    return res.to_bytes((res.bit_length() + 7) // 8, byteorder='big')

def base45encode_nl(buf: bytes) -> str:
    base45_nl_charset = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ $%*+-./:"
    res = ""
    divident = int.from_bytes(buf, 'big')
    
    while(divident > 0): 
      divident, remainder = divmod(divident, 45)
      res += base45_nl_charset[remainder]

    return reversed_string(res)

def reversed_string(a_string):
    return a_string[::-1]

def asn1decode(d: asn1.Decoder) -> List:
    res = []
    while not d.eof():
        tag = d.peek()
        if tag.typ == asn1.Types.Primitive:            
            tag, value = d.read()
            res.append(value)
        elif tag.typ == asn1.Types.Constructed:            
            d.enter()
            res.append(asn1decode(d))
            d.leave()
    return res

def asn1encode(d: asn1.Encoder,l: List) -> asn1.Encoder:
    d.enter(asn1.Types.Constructed)
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        if isinstance(x, list):            
            d = asn1encode(d, x)
        else:
            d.write(x)
    d.leave()
    return d

import json
import sys
import zlib
import base45
import cbor2
from cose.messages import CoseMessage 

data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

b45_decoded = base45decode_nl(data)
print('before decoding / encoding')
print(b45_decoded)

asn1_decoder = asn1.Decoder()
asn1_decoder.start(b45_decoded)
asn1_obj = asn1decode(asn1_decoder)[0]
print('decoded asn1_obj')
print(asn1_obj)

asn1_encoder = asn1.Encoder()
asn1_encoder.start()
asn1_encoder = asn1encode(asn1_encoder, [asn1_obj])
asn1_encoded_output = asn1_encoder.output()

print('after decoding / encoding')
print(asn1_encoded_output)
```

The begin of the output looks like this:

b'0\x82\x02j\x02

and

b'? \x82\x02p? \x82\x02k\x02\

I suspect the asn1encode method to be wrong.
What should I change to the asn1encode method to get the exact same output?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer ...

You cannot use python asn1.Encoder unless you know the specification of the data you want to encode. The first thing you have to do is to look of the ASN.1 specification of the data carried by your QR-code.

Long answer ...

To understand what I mean by that, you can have a look at https://pypi.org/project/asn1tools/ which will show you what the process is when you want to use asn1/python

Try the following test ...

In your code, replace

```
b45_decoded = base45decode_nl(data)
print('before decoding / encoding')
print(b45_decoded)
```

with

```
b45_decoded = base45decode_nl(data)
print('before decoding / encoding')
print(b45_decoded.hex())
```

The result will be a string containing only hexa chars (0 to F)

```
before decoding / encoding
3082026a020100022012e8a6e4693ced7bfa111227f75134aca71914358d00c34b17ebe49eb ....
```

Copy the whole data and paste it in the Decode tab of https://asn1.io/asn1playground/

The output will be

```
OSS Nokalva TLV Print Utility  Version 8.6.1
Copyright (C) 1997-2021 OSS Nokalva, Inc.  All rights reserved.


30 82026A(618)
  02 01 00
  02 20 12E8A6E4693CED7BFA111227F75134ACA71914358D00C34B17EBE49EB2C4784D
  02 8180(128) 4629505D6ED76C40573A65B4F3681C4B921C545B9A37819DC1A80B08097291...
  02 39 442A6F5B7CC5456E9CD4685041C81199624C6920207EF947BC995204AAAA9F61E719...
  02 81FF(255) 0F22E0284AE0CF97EE79144A2F4B52E057D1D0DAAD86C7DEA69444A3311B73...
  02 4B 008E134CAC21D0C66F56FF440764BA8F84D06B4C323F531AB02406AF29DF037807B7...
  30 36
    02 0F 601A0802042610ACAEA65A86865A65
    02 01 63
    02 01 63
    02 0A 626C646E686C6C686061
    02 02 646B
    02 02 0085
    02 02 0085
    02 02 6663
    02 01 6F
```

You only know that the data is valid and is a structure of 7 parts. The 7th parts being a structure of 9 parts. This does not tell you what it means (again you need the spec for that).

Note also that this is a Tag/Length/Value encoding

Another thing ...

When you run your script, you see

```
decoded asn1_obj
[0, 8552691641371642315207690017304824071043033037718558536544370073022402689101, 49268998317399832353736153768064371574626738522454049754099967437769709104310153609419233826877129804699795832362376712815509777453876457088841057013114352195643598128717108189839059529627445516705110559750713315964799043200407446690141492417247324685581653291574436663012628249066333485906592079172004705549, 49545515259154895522776867107959247032241047651980572443481917331143789403307139106555023968391340296360761238102083435099286993359857518, 7463954613777398261540270129601931803174222687130155761347994847425322491183229539732191198415826129672984792140024846081031144727556269931620272207040926338693607156199863455849443514025962426861121889546981280059686356901102682907001113258526002924172374302439709804314739830145508425336941142618773720272632415685260123356955161489134413604652892038340458427564488213207319660351733296444266493507445217438295664429771376840180237292580120261971321393055748802007069008017175471042800839302970504855484030669136380196262086189703554019361768087619371773861096653352702590133156777381984232268805659708171263123, 8995728107811269294519662596375119434427697506197921896277098071616873267360774813635548449786430125954107935654004828703451862806879219403683135630175078760507502448619423267753, [498988475518323990323119632714979941, 99, 99, 464791400517651978018913, 25707, 133, 133, 26211, 111]]
```

The data is not easy to read because this is an array of raw data presented as integer. But you can clearly recognize the small numbers

- The first 0 is the first part of the structure above
- The 99 in the end are part 2 and part 3 of the sub structure above (hexa 63)

You notice that the tags are not in the array returned by asn1decode()

So, these are a lot of reasons why your script cannot do what you want it to do :)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the Python ASN.1 tools, but if the data is BER encoded I've always thought that the TLV nature of it ought to make it possible to decode to an object, and re-encode that object to get back to the original (possibly with some variations if there are SETs or SET OFs). I think that if you try that decode with Nokalva's ASN1 Viewer (not free), you'll get a more complete dump of the message and its structure. What's unlikely is mutating the decoded object without knowledge of the schema, because there's things that aren't in the BER wire format (e.g. constraints).